# How to implement synchronous Request-Response app using activeMQ NMS and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, jms, activemq-classic, nms

I could send messages to Queue('test.queue') with the producer(Also i could recieve the same at the other end)
But i could not recieve reply msg from reply destination('confirm') with the consumer.receive() method.
No error.but consumer does not recieve any msg.Please get me out of it.
Code has been given below:-

```
    class Program
{
    private const String URI = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    private const String DESTINATION = "test.queue";
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(URI);
        connectionFactory.ClientId = connectionFactory.ClientIdGenerator.GenerateId(); ;
        IMessageProducer prod;
        String s = String.Empty;
        while (s.ToLower() != "exit")
        {
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            ISession ses = connectionFactory.CreateConnection().CreateSession();
            prod = ses.CreateProducer();
            IMessage msg=ses.CreateTextMessage(s);
            NmsDestinationAccessor destinationResolver = new NmsDestinationAccessor();
            IDestination destination = destinationResolver.ResolveDestinationName(ses, DESTINATION);
            IDestination replyDestination = destinationResolver.ResolveDestinationName(ses, "confirm");
            IMessageConsumer consumer = ses.CreateConsumer(replyDestination);
            prod.Send(destination, msg);
            IMessage im= consumer.Receive();
            ses.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine(im.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that it should be a synchronous recieve for consumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not a activeMQ specialist but I know in most JMS implementations (which I think NMS pretty much follows 1:1) you need to call Start() on your connection to allow consuming to begin

Comment: This is correct, without a call to start() on the Connection a consumer will not receive any messages.